# Android - Nested GridView inside RecyclerView problem

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a chat application, which can display images within messages.
The messages are CardView bubbles inside a RecyclerView, but if the message contains two or more images, the content of that RecyclerView element is going to be a GridView that shows the images.

Until now the app is smooth, until I scroll up and then scroll down, the images in GridView is going to be swapped with others in other messages in the conversation , and sometimes the items becomes invisible:

**BEFORE SCROLLING:**
[image]

**AFTER SCROLLING:**
[image]

As you can See; the numbers overlay on the images I made for debugging purposes to count how many items are passed and what is actually shown,
after scrolling now the items are totally hidden and nothing shows up, instead, it shows a debugging TextView to the right which tells how many items are in the array of image paths, which is passed to the GridView.

The GridView adapter I use :

```
package com.application.netapp.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.application.netapp.Attachments;
import com.application.netapp.ConversationActivity;
import com.application.netapp.ConversationViewMoreActivity;
import com.application.netapp.DB_Helper;
import com.application.netapp.MediaPreviewActivity;
import com.application.netapp.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConversationGridviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConversationGridviewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> Image;
    Context context;
    Activity activity;
    String Att_ID;
    String contactID;
    SQLiteDatabase dbData;
    DB_Helper dbHelper;

    // constructor
    public ConversationGridviewAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, ArrayList<String> Image, String Att_ID, String contactID) {
        super();
        dbHelper = new DB_Helper(context);
        dbData = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.context = context;
        //this.Image = Attachments.getAttachmentsPaths(Att_ID, dbData);
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Att_ID = Att_ID;
        this.contactID = contactID;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.convo_staggered_gridview, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        System.out.println("***************************************************************************************************** onViewAttachedToWindow()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // setting image resource
        viewHolder.showmoreView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.showmoreCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.showmoreCount.setText(getItemCount()+".");
        viewHolder.imgview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        if(i<=3)
        {
            viewHolder.imgview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.imgview.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(Image.get(i))));
            // TODO : onClick OpenMedia
            if(i != 3)
            {
                viewHolder.imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Attachments.openImage(activity, new File(Image.get(i)));
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if(Image.size()>4 && i == 3)
                {
                    // don't open onClick, open "More" Layout
                    viewHolder.imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, ConversationViewMoreActivity.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("attachmentID", Att_ID);
                            myIntent.putExtra("contactID", contactID);
                            myIntent.putExtra("list", (Serializable) Image);
                            activity.startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder.imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Attachments.openImage(activity, new File(Image.get(i)));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            System.out.println("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT :: INSIDE the staggeredGridView : i="+i);
            if (Image.size()==3 && i==1)
            {
                // If the media count is 3, adjust the layout so it appears neat
                int w = 300;
                int h = 530;
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w,h);
                viewHolder.imgview.setLayoutParams(parms);
                // TODO : onClick OpenMedia
                viewHolder.imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Attachments.openImage(activity, new File(Image.get(i)));
                    }
                });
            }
            if (Image.size()>4 && i==3)
            {
                // If the media count is more than 4, show only 4 media and an overlay of (+n) in the fourth media while n is the number of
                // additional media. when clicked, will open the whole message media layout.
                int count = Image.size() - 4;
                viewHolder.showmoreView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.showmoreCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.showmoreCount.setText("+"+count);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.imgview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Image.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imgview;
        public View showmoreView;
        public TextView showmoreCount;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // getting ImageView reference
            imgview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            showmoreView = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.media_showmore_view);
            showmoreCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.media_showmore_text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of onbindViewholder(). Also a screen shot of problem will help visualizing the problem more easily.

Comment: When scrolling bindviewholder is called values of position ( i ) changes, Don't rely on " i " in your IF condition. remake your logic.

  if (Image.size()==3 )